# Extraction part of image that matches to a mask in OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, mask

In a `OpenCV` application with `Python`, i have a mask and an `RGB` image, i want to extract part of image that matches to mask but i dont know how.

for example this is a mask:
[image]

and i want to do like this:
[image]

i do this:

```
temp = cv2.bitwise_and(img ,img, mask=feature_map)
```

but it gives me and error:

```
cv2.error: /Users/mee/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1589: error: (-215) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function binary_op
```

Comment: I don't have the setup to try it now but, feels like `(mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S)` part is saying that your mask needs to be a `CV_8UC3` matrix.

Comment: Use copyTo to a black initialized image, with the inverted mask

Comment: @seleciii44 I would expect the mask to be a single channel, but I think your observation about the type is correct. I would also expect the mask to be inverted before applying to the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png',0)
im = cv2.imread('guy.png')
mask_inv =  255 - mask;
final_im = mask_inv*im
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your mask as being object mask pixels value is 255 and background pixels value is 0. After that you can apply and operation or multiply operation for each color channel of RGB image with new mask .